# ¿Reciben algún nombre concreto las composiciones poéticas compuestas por versos de cabo roto?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, poesía, literatura

Entre los preliminares del *Quijote*, el autor incluyó una serie de composiciones poéticas burlescas. La primera es una llamada *[Urganda la desconocida](http://www.cervantesvirtual.com/obra-visor/el-ingenioso-hidalgo-don-quijote-de-la-mancha-6/html/05f86699-4b53-4d9b-8ab8-b40ab63fb0b3_2.html#I_4_)*, que comienza así:

> *Si de llegarte a los bue-,
>
>   Libro, fueres con letu-,
>
>   No te dirá el boquirru-
>
>   Que no pones bien los de-.
>
>   Mas si el pan no se te cue-
>
>   Por ir a manos de idio-,
>
>   Verás de manos a bo-
>
>   Aun no dar una en el cla-,
>
>   Si bien se comen las ma-
>
>   Por mostrar que son curio-.*

Siempre me ha llamado la atención esta composición, ya que si nos fijamos, a pesar de que a cada verso le falta la última sílaba, la rima de los mismos es consonante en la que queda como última sílaba de cada uno.

Encuentro en la Wikipedia [la siguiente explicación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urganda_la_Desconocida) (negritas mías):

> En las poesías burlescas incluidas entre los preliminares del Quijote, Miguel de Cervantes Saavedra incluyó uno a nombre de Urganda la Desconocida, que es el primero de todos y **está compuesto por versos de cabo roto**, a los que le falta la sílaba final de cada línea.

¿Es "versos de cabo roto" la denominación correcta para los versos de este tipo de composiciones? ¿Reciben algún nombre concreto las composiciones poéticas compuestas exclusivamente por versos de cabo roto?

Bonus (aunque sea una pregunta más de literatura que del idioma): ¿Qué otras composiciones (más o menos famosas) existen con este tipo de versos?

Comment: http://dle.rae.es/?id=bfpCTfM **verso de cabo roto** 
1. m. Métr. verso que tiene suprimida o cortada la sílaba o sílabas que siguen a la última acentuada.verso de cabo roto


Es decir que efectivamente "verso de cabo roto" es la denominación correcta para esos versos. Y fijate que no tiene por qué faltar solo la sílaba final, sino que son todas las sílabas que siguen a la acentuada

Comment: @user17232 qué lapsus, yo busqué en la definición de "cabo" y no se me ocurrió buscar en la de "verso". Bien visto.

Answer (score 3):

El [DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bfpCTfM) define

> **verso de cabo roto**
>   1. m. Métr. verso que tiene suprimida o cortada la sílaba o sílabas que siguen a la última acentuada.verso de cabo roto

Es decir que efectivamente "**verso de cabo roto**" es la denominación correcta para esos versos. Y  que no tiene por qué faltar solo la sílaba final, sino que son **todas las sílabas que siguen a la acentuada**.

[Aquí](http://www.prometeodigital.org/Descarga/FONDO_DOCUMENTAL/FDP022_MARIOL_CABOROTO.doc) Luis Mario indica que "... que, por dificultoso y superficial, no prendió en el ánimo de los poetas. " y recoge la invención de los mismos por Alonso Alvarez de Soria, anterior a Cervantes. Transcribo:

> ...Cervantes, a quien siempre se tuvo por creador de esa modalidad,
>   aunque no fuera así.
>
> Y no fue así porque hubo un antecedente, que relata Ricardo Palma en
>   sus Tradiciones peruanas, donde se hace un retrato cruel de una época
>   remota, cuando la humanidad entraba en el siglo XVII. Resulta que a
>   principios de 1605 salió de la imprenta El Quijote, donde hay décimas
>   de cabo roto, como la que empieza: "Advierte que es desati-,/ siendo
>   de vidrio el teja-..." Pero ya desde un año antes eran populares en
>   Sevilla las coplas de cabo roto. Según Palma, que tomó los datos de un
>   viejo periódico de Madrid, Alonso Alvarez de Soria, joven inquieto,
>   calavera y burlón, creó el verso de cabo roto en alusión a los
>   bravucones de Triana que, presumiendo de valientes, dejaban sin
>   pronunciar la última sílaba de un período, fanfarronamente. Pero un
>   día Alvarez de Soria fue muy lejos con sus burlas y, para fatalidad
>   suya, envolvió con ellas a quien tenía poco sentido del buen humor,
>   nada menos que el Asistente de Sevilla, Bernardino de Avellaneda,
>   señor del Castillo, quien se las arregló para colgar al poeta en forma
>   afrentosa y sin juicio previo.
>
> Nada valió entonces que otros poetas sevillanos pidieran perdón para
>   su colega. Y concluye Ricardo Palma esta, su “Tradición española”, con
>   la siguiente afirmación: "En cuando a los versos de cabo roto, de que
>   fue el inventor, (Palma se refiere a Alvarez de Soria) a pesar del
>   empeño de Cervantes por popularizarlos, puede decirse que no han hecho
>   ni harán fortuna. Nacieron con desgracia"

Con esa información, dudo que haya muchas más composiciones con versos de cabo roto.

[**Aquí**](http://piramideacostada.blogspot.com.es/2017/04/decimas-de-cabo-roto-jugando-con-la.html) hay algunas más, incluyendo una de  Alonso Álvarez de Soria, el supuesto inventor de este verso, dedicada a Lope de Vega:

> A Lope
>
> Envió Lope de Ve-
>   al señor don Juan de Argui-
>   el libro del peregri-
>   a que diga si está bue-
>   y es tan noble y tan discre-
>   que estando como está ma-
>   dice es otro Garcila-
>   en su traza y compostu-
>   mas luego entre si quien du-
>   no diga que está bella-

Por otro lado he encontrado algo *parecido* [**aquí**](http://franciscoacuyo.blogspot.com.es/2012/07/versos-de-cabo-doblado-por-jose.html), en que en vez de truncar la palabra se pasan las sílabas al verso siguiente (y lo denominan **versos de cabo doblado**), como:

> ¡Oh nube, cuánta calén-
>   dula en flor espera llu-
>   via que le niegas tan hu-
>   raña y avara sabien-
>   do que es el agua sostén
>   de la flor y la alegrí-
>   a de cuerpos y alma ardi-
>   dos! ¡No celes sol, y col-
>   ma la sed con unos gol-
>   pes generosos y flui-
>   dos de ti!

Comment: @walen: en uno de los enlaces que he puesto (http://piramideacostada.blogspot.com.es/2017/04/decimas-de-cabo-roto-jugando-con-la.html) vienen algunas modernas. Pero vamos, que no es un formato muy común